# How to print a large plot to a small file from R on NetBSD?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to plot a relatively large dataset on a remote server (NetBSD), because my local machine does not have sufficient memory for the job. The method I have used successfully to save smaller datasets on my local machine is not working on the remote server. Here's what I want to do:

```
ggsave(filename="myplot.png", plot=p)
```

The trouble is that when I try to do this on the server, it pops open an X11 window and I get warning messages about X not supporting transparency, along with an empty plot.

I can save the plot as a pdf, but the file size ends up being in the hundreds of megabytes, presumably because the pdf is preserving each of millions of semi-transparent points in the plot. So, given that I need to use transparency to deal with over-plotting, how can I save the plot as an image file not bigger than a couple MB?

Comment: Try specifying height, width, and dpi in your `ggsave` call. I have used this work-around on Mac OS to prevent a blank device window from opening. I guess `ggsave` is trying to use the current device dimensions, but because there is no current device it tries to create one?

Comment: That's not doing it, I think I might need cairo installed.

Comment: Depending on what your plot looks like, do you really need all those millions of points? You could try sampling from the points to produce a representative example that may be visually equivalent.